# How can I include break lines in mysql records?

Tags: php, mysql, formatting

When someone types in the following to be put into a database:

```
Hello,

My name is John and I am 22, and looking for a good time.

My Phone Number is:
555-NOT-REAL

Sincerely,
John D.
```

I want the break lines to stay there, but it seems that when I pull the value back out it comes out as follows.

```
Hello, My name is John and I am 22, and looking for a good time. My Phone Number is: 555-NOT-REAL Sincerely,John D.
```

Is there a special kind of field that keeps the format of the text that is put in? I am pretty sure that it is already in there because when I look at the field in the database the breaklines do appear. Maybe it is the way I am retrieving it?

I prefer not to have to code something to put in HTML tags, haha. Thanks!

Comment: Wich type of field are you using to type the data?
The key is to use textarea

Comment: Sorry missunderstood you.
Replace the "\n" with "<br>" after getting the data from DB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are displaying the text in the browser, you *have* to put HTML tags in. Browsers do not automatically put linebreaks for you. This is most commonly done with the [`nl2br`](http://www.php.net/nl2br) function:

```
nl2br($message);
```

However, you could also wrap your text around the [`<pre>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4) tag, but I don't recommend it:

```
<pre>$message</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Read: [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string= "this
is
a
string";

echo $string. "<br />";

echo nl2br($string);
?>
```

output:

```
this is a string
this
is
a
string
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly (it's been a while since I've played with MySQL), you should replace line breaks with the escape sequence \n