# Show new lines and spaces?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am coding a guestbook and I want new lines and spaces to be shown when I show the posts?

when I post a thread now everything is shown on one line.

help!

Comment: related: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785961/replacing-a-new-line-with-its-html-equivalent-in-php> , <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791330/how-can-i-include-break-lines-in-mysql-records> and many, many more...

Answer (score 3):

Use `nl2br()`. Basically it's prepending every newline character with `<br />`.

Comment: Just a nit: there is no need for a space before the "/".

Comment: Needed or not that's what nl2br() returns ;) http://php.net/nl2br: "Returns string  with '<br />' or '<br>' inserted before all newlines. "

Comment: nl2br() returns <br /> for legacy user-agent compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659208/why-br-and-not-br/1659222#1659222

Comment: Actually, the space before "/" is/was needed for legacy support of some older browsers, but not nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Use this function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

**nl2br()** will convert new lines into <br/> tags, so you will get new lines.